# Is this the most efficient way to append an array to a slice?

Tags: rust

I have the following code to add bytes to a pre-allocated slice `buf` (the necessary size is known in advance)

```rs
pub struct Encoder<'a> {
    pos: usize,
    buf: &'a mut [u8],
}

impl Encoder<'_> {
    fn put_bytes_const<const N: usize>(&mut self, bytes: &[u8; N]) -> Result<()> {
        ensure_len_is_sufficient!(self, N);
        self.buf[self.pos..self.pos + N].copy_from_slice(bytes);   
        self.pos += N;
        Ok(())
    }
}

// EDIT: add definition of the macro as requested by @Caesar
macro_rules! ensure_len_is_sufficient {
    ($this:ident, $len:expr) => {
        if $len + $this.pos >= $this.buf.len() {
            return Err(EncodeError::TooLarge);
        }
    };
}
```

This is O(n), is there a more efficient way to do it ?

Comment: If you're copying N elements, I don't think it's possible to do any better than O(N) with any data structure. With a different data structure (e.g. a linked list) you might be able to _transfer ownership of a subregion_ of one container into another with O(1) complexity, but I seriously doubt a linked list is the right approach here.

Comment: This can actually be O(1) depending on what N is (may be it's 1/2/4/8/16/32) and what CPU you're compiling for.

Comment: Very interesting. How do I do that, or is the compiler smart enough to do such optimizations on its own?

Comment: @stepan If you mean copying multiple elements at once by e.g. blitting a type larger than a byte, that's still O(N). (Constants factor out, it's still linear time complexity.)

Comment: @cdhowie if we assume a non-ancient x86-64 then mov is roughly same cost whether it's 1 byte or 8 bytes. So in that sense N=1 is the same as N=8. And it's constant - just 1 instruction. Let me clarify: I'm saying that in cases where N is a certain value (usually <= 32) then for most CPUs this is already O(1).

Comment: @MidnightExigent yes, LLVM does it on its own. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/a6n8a15z4  copy_16, copy_8, copy_4 all use just one of load+store instruction for the actual copying (movups/mov).

Comment: @MidnightExigent Whether Rust is able to optimize the bounds check on the slice access is surprisingly subtly dependent on how you do the buf size check (and whether you use `self.buf[self.pos..][..N]` — I don't seem to be able to get rid of the check with that.) (It's probably also dependent on the context this function will be inlined into…). Would you mind adding the definition of `ensure_len_is_sufficient`? I'm also wondering whether what you want wouldn't be better implemented by `Cursor`s or `Vec`s, the latter wouldn't require buf to be initialized before `extend_from_slice`ing.

Comment: Hi @Caesar, thanks for the comment, I edited the post to add the definition of the macro. The size needed is known in advance, I don't know yet what the underlying storage for slice is going to be (probably `bytes::Bytes` tho). I haven't considered `Cursor` as I thought it is only useful when reading data from an underlying buffer

Comment: I see. (Side note: `Cursor` [does implement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Cursor.html#impl-Write) `Write`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: You're unlikely to be able to significantly improve the performance of memcopy. Depending on the size of your buffers, where you get them from, and where the result of encoder ends up, you might be able to not copy the buffers at all and only record a reference to them, but I doubt even that will do a lot on buffers <1k.

There is one place that can be improved, though: looking at the [assembler output](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=ff490291fcf26f044d1647c2028e8f0b) (You have to add some non-parameterized function for actual code to be generated:

```rust
pub fn foo_32(x: &mut Encoder, bytes: &[u8; 32]) -> Result<(), …> {
    x.put_bytes_const(bytes)
}
```

) it seems that your function references `core::slice::index::slice_index_order_fail`, which means that the compiler is not fully able to optimize the bounds check when slicing `buf`.
The reason for that is that while arithmetic overflow [panics](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9631b0fff865d82c5e69096482dd6353) in debug mode, Rust doesn't assume that it doesn't appear in release mode and must still guarantee that no memory unsoundness occurs. Constructing a slice with an inverted range may cause unsoundness, and `self.pos + N` could, without further hints from the surrounding code, overflow.
You can allow the optimizer to skip this check by adding the condition `… || $this.pos >= usize::MAX - N` or `… || $this.pos + N < N` to your manual bounds check, which shortens the assembly for the function and I thus assume that it may result in a tiny performance increase.
This optimization is pretty fickle, though. Assuming you had instead written your slice access as `self.buf[self.pos..][..N]` (which doesn't have an addition, so no overflow), you would have to formulate the condition as `$this.buf.len() < $this.pos || $this.buf.len() - $this.pos < N`.

Whether this increases performance in practice though is up to a lot more factors: LLVM is likely to inline `put_bytes_const`, and there it might gain more clues about whether the overflow can actually happen from the surrounding code.
In any case, I somehow doubt the performance impact of this function is large enough to make a difference in your application.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Yes, I agree, the performance gains from this function probably won't affect the performance of the application in a significant way as it is a micro-optimization. I'll be using the `self.buf[self.pos..][..N]` form tho as it looks cleaner and doesn't cause overflow